# Can i communicate between two PC using PCIe for high transfer speed, if possible how can i communicate?

Tags: networking, iot, ethernet, lan, raspberry-pi4

I have a raspberry pi 4 and a pc, I have to transfer files at very high speed than Ethernet and WIFI
if any possible methods are there Please tell me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure if you're saying you want to transfer files over something other than wifi or Ethernet? If so, USB A to USB A should work for you. PCIe are downstream slots which you would be unable to connect to another system using that method.  If you are able to plug up to each of the systems using ethernet, that's probably your easiest choice. As long as you bridge the connections and allow file printing and sharing, you should be able to see the system in your file explorer.